# Bafflement with LED ceiling lights

Tags: wiring, lighting, led

I have two office lights, wired in parallel that were switched for LED a couple of years ago. 
For over a year they worked fine. They are the type with multiple little LEDs not LED bulbs. On switching on & off they alternated through warm / cold / middle light.

Unexpectedly both stopped working and now extremely intermittently turn on when trying the switch.

- I checked the voltage with an multimeter, all correct at the switch and where voltage enters both light fittings. Voltage is there with the switch on, reading is 244V. I haven't checked around individual LEDs but given the light is intermittently coming on I don't think that the LEDs themselves have blown.
- I checked in the loft all wires are still secure, not chewed or loose (as the voltage suggests anyway)
- I changed the light switch - no change. the lights came on & off briefly when I changed it but then just as instantly stopped working / responding again.
- I changed one of the lights for an alternative light (completely switched the actual light & wired a new one in) - this briefly turned on & off to the switch, then both lights lit when switched on & off & then nothing again.
- In desperation I changed the wires for the upstairs & downstairs circuit breakers at the distribution board to see if that made a difference, no change. (all other lights upstairs have been working fine including an LED one in the hall).

what the heck is going on? I don't know where to go with this next!? I'd appreciate any suggestions

Comment: did you check the neutral wire for that circuit back at the breaker panel, or any neutral wire-nut bundles?  People often forget it's just as important as the hot...

Comment: Are you saying the fixtures have the ability to change the Kelvin temp by flipping the switch repeatedly ?  If so perhaps the on board controllers in the fixtures are failing.